# Gmail Chrome shortcut + unread message count in Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: gmail, notifications, windows-7

Is there a way to display the unread messages count in the Windows 7 taskbar icon that I pinned there after creating a Chrome desktop shortcut for Gmail? Sort of like favicon notifiers but it should work for the taskbar icon.

Gmail Notifier Plus works fine but is standalone application that adds another (unnecessary) icon to the taskbar, opens inbox in my default browser etc. I'd much rather display the message count on the Chrome app button itself.

Comment: I'd like to know this too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with IE 9.

Unfortunately, you're using Google Chrome and I don't see a way to do that with Chrome.